# How to form table within for loop?

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-table

This is how the looping looks like:

```
for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++) {
    new_array.push(data[i].catalog_name,data[i].price);
    for (var j=0;j < new_array.length; j++){
        $("#print_receipt").append("<table><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Unit Price</th></tr><tr>");
        $.each(new_array[j], function( index, value ) {
            $("#print_receipt").append(value);
            if(index == 1) {
                $("#print_receipt").append("</td></tr>");
            }
        });                         
        $("#print_receipt").append("</td></tr></table>");
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

**

> But the desired output is:

**

**Item Name**                          **Unit price**
Sistem Autodownline         100
Karipap Pusing Ayu           8

EDIT:

```
 for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++)
                     {

                        new_array.push(data[i].catalog_name,data[i].price);
                        $("#print_receipt").append("<table><thead><tr><th>Item name</th><th>Unit Price</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>");
                        for (var j=0;j < new_array.length; j++){


                            $.each(new_array[j], function( index, value ) {
                        $("#print_receipt").append("<table><tr><td>");
                          $("#print_receipt").append(value+"</td></tr></table>");
                          if(index == 1)
                          {
                              $("#print_receipt").append("</td></tr></tbody></table>");
                          }
                        });                         

                         }

       }
```

Comment: You are appending everything to the same element, not creating a `TABLE/[TBODY]/TR/TD` hierarchy. You need to keep append to the appropriate elements of the table.

Comment: You need to understand how `append()` works.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, please look at my edited post, still I can't get it right for the content

Comment: Working on a example for you (unless someone beats me to it) :)

Comment: Answer added: I am not sure I understand your data from the code shown. Seems like there should be multiple rows per table. Can you provide a sample of the data too?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your code as if append takes strings and simply appends them.

You want to create DOM elements for the parts of the tree you need to add to. Something like this (not tested):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  new_array.push(data[i].catalog_name, data[i].price);
  for (var j = 0; j < new_array.length; j++) {
    var $table = $("<table><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Unit Price</th></tr><tr>");
    $("#print_receipt").append($table);
    var $row = $('tr').appendTo($table);
    $.each(new_array[j], function(index, value) {
      $row.append($('td').html(value));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: The data implied for the question seems to be missing multiple rows, so waiting on sample data to complete this :)

Comment: new_array.push(data[i].catalog_name, data[i].price); contains all the data where each item represents a column in a table also an array. So that the second loop $.each is looped through this array to get multiple rows per column too'

Comment: @Keren: Then the only remaining question is: Did you intend to add one table with heading per row? If not move it up before the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    data = [["Sistem Autodownline", 100], ["Karipap Pusing Ayu", 8]];

    szData="<table><thead><tr><th>Item name</th><th>Unit Price</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        szData  =  szData   +    "<tr>";
        for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++)
            {
            szData  =  szData   +  "<td>" + data[i][j] +  "</td>";  
            }
        szData  =  szData   +    "</tr>";
    }

    $("#print_receipt").html(szData)
});
```